# Calling Textblock from Xaml to the c# class

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, windows-phone-8, project

I am developing an windos phone application and database is required but I cant call the the textblock from xaml to the c# class to bind them. 
here is my xaml code

```
 <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="Smart Parking" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="History" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ListBox x:Name="ListData">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock x:Name=  "DateTxt"  Text="{Binding Date}"   TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                            <TextBlock x:Name=  "TimeTxt"  Text="{Binding Time}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                            <TextBlock x:Name=  "ZoneTxt"  Text="{Binding Zone}"  TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name=  "FloorTxt" Text="{Binding Floor}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name=  "LatTxt"   Text="{Binding location_latitude}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  />
                            <TextBlock x:Name=  "LongTxt"  Text="{Binding location_longitude}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        </StackPanel>
                 </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox> 
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I want to call all the textblock in the class below in addinfo class so that I store them in the database.

```
public partial class History : PhoneApplicationPage
{





    // string dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "db.sqlite");
    ObservableCollection<historyTableSQlite> DB_HistoryList = new ObservableCollection<historyTableSQlite>();

    public History()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
       // AddInfo();
        this.Loaded += ReadHistoryList_Loaded;
    }



    private void ReadHistoryList_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ReadAllContactsList dbhistory = new ReadAllContactsList();
        DB_HistoryList = dbhistory.GetAllHistory();//Get all DB contacts
        ListData.ItemsSource = DB_HistoryList.OrderByDescending(i => i.Id).ToList();//Latest contact ID can Display first

    }


    public void AddInfo(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        DbHelper Db_helper = new DbHelper();
        Db_helper.Insert(new historyTableSQlite(
        //I want to call all the textblock here Is there anyway to do it.
        ));

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your text blocks are inside the DataTemplate, you cannot directly access them in code behind file.

What you can do means,just hook up the Loaded event of the text block and keep a reference of the text block.then you will get the access.

Your Data template will look like this

```
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Loaded="DateTxt_Loaded" x:Name=  "DateTxt"  Text="{Binding Date}"   TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                            <TextBlock Loaded="TimeTxt_Loaded" x:Name=  "TimeTxt"  Text="{Binding Time}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                            <TextBlock  Loaded="ZoneTxt_Loaded"  x:Name=  "ZoneTxt"  Text="{Binding Zone}"  TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            <TextBlock Loaded="FloorTxt_Loaded" x:Name=  "FloorTxt" Text="{Binding Floor}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            <TextBlock Loaded="LatTxt_Loaded" x:Name=  "LatTxt"   Text="{Binding location_latitude}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  />
                            <TextBlock Loaded="LongTxt_Loaded" x:Name=  "LongTxt"  Text="{Binding location_longitude}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
```

and in you code behind c# class looks like

```
    TextBlock DateTxtBlock;
    TextBlock TimeTxtBlock;
    TextBlock ZoneTxtBlock;
    TextBlock FloorTxtBlock;
    TextBlock LatTxtBlock;
    TextBlock LongTxtBlock;

    private void DateTxt_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTxtBlock = sender as TextBlock;
    }

    private void TimeTxt_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TimeTxtBlock = sender as TextBlock;
    }

    private void ZoneTxt_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ZoneTxtBlock = sender as TextBlock;
    }

    private void FloorTxt_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FloorTxtBlock = sender as TextBlock;
    }

    private void LatTxt_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LatTxtBlock = sender as TextBlock;
    }

    private void LongTxt_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LongTxtBlock = sender as TextBlock;
    }
```

Then you can access all the textblocks in your AddInfo() method.for example if you want to get the value of DateTxtBlock like     DateTxtBlock.Text.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Sorry if its a stupid question but how could I reference textblock ?

Comment: @vivekshahi you can declare your text blocks as private properties in your c# class like "TextBlock MyTextBlock".

Comment: I have tried using this but while calling the textblock in Dbhelper.insert() ,it still does not call the textblock

Comment: @vivekshahi i think now its clear please refer the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's in a ListBox. A ListBox will have a collection of items.

I created a model class to match those values you're binding to...

```
public class PhoneModel
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string Zone { get; set; }
    public string Floor { get; set; }
    public string location_latitude { get; set; }
    public string location_longitude { get; set; }
}
```

I've added items to the ListBox...

```
ListData.Items.Add(new PhoneModel
{
    Date = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(),
    Time = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(),
    Zone = "PST",
    Floor = "10th Floor",
    location_latitude = "35.45112",
    location_longitude = "-115.42622"
});

ListData.Items.Add(new PhoneModel
{
    Date = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(),
    Time = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(),
    Zone = "CST",
    Floor = "11th Floor",
    location_latitude = "32.45112",
    location_longitude = "-105.42622"
});

ListData.Items.Add(new PhoneModel
{
    Date = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(),
    Time = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(),
    Zone = "EST",
    Floor = "12th Floor",
    location_latitude = "34.45112",
    location_longitude = "-112.42622"
});
```

Now I will get a reference to the first row in the ListBox...

```
public void AddInfo(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // You need to reference a specific row of your ListBox control.

    // Make sure there is at least 1 item.
    if (ListData.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        // Get a reference to the first bound object (data that is bound to the text blocks).
        var item = (PhoneModel)ListData.Items[0];

    }
}
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much for this sample but I have to add all those values in the database as you can see in the AddInfo() ?Is that possible with this sample